# I'm trying to register for twitch using the selenium library in python, but it gives such an error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, twitch

I encountered the problem mentioned in the title.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

[image]
I have specified user agent in the code but it still gives this error.
What should I do to make the code run?

Comment: Why do you need to specify a user agent at all? Just remove the options portion of the code and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're obviously getting detected:)

Try using [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles) or undetected-chromedriver

Example script:

```py
from selenium_profiles.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium_profiles.profiles import profiles
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By  # locate elements
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions


profile = profiles.Windows()
options = ChromeOptions()
mydriver = Chrome(profile, options=options, uc_driver=False,executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
# mydriver.options.add_argument("--headless=new")

driver = mydriver.start()  # or .Android

# get url
driver.get('https://abrahamjuliot.github.io/creepjs/')  # test fingerprint

input("Press ENTER to exit: ")
driver.quit()  # Execute on the End!
```

Disclosure: I am the Author of Selenium-Profiles